# vue-route path comparison issus

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Here is my route setting.

```
routes:[
{
  path: "/test/:area/mybox/:address/:id/:box",
  name: "BoxManage",
  component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "box" */ "@/views/BoxManage.vue"),
  props: true,
  children: []
},
{
  path: "/test/:area/mybox/:address/:id/:box/detail/:port",
  name: "BoxDetail",
  component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "box" */ "@/views/BoxDetail.vue"),
  props: true,
  children: []
}
]
```

Here is some code in template

```
<v-btn to="/test/111/mybox/222/333/444"> Manage </v-btn>
<v-btn to="/test/111/mybox/222/333/444/detail/1"> Detail </v-btn>
```

After I click Detail button, Manage button is light on together. it mean these two button is the same path ?
It should not the same path, is there has any error in my code ?

Comment: Can you try putting /detail/:port before just :id/:box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use `exact`. `exact` match the link. Without this, '/' will match every route. You can find more information about the exact prop on the [vue-router documentation about exact](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#exact).

So you have to change it into theses code lines:

`<v-btn to="/test/111/mybox/222/333/444" exact> Manage </v-btn>`

`<v-btn to="/test/111/mybox/222/333/444/detail/1" exact> Detail </v-btn>`

If you need use a **custom active class**, you can use `exact-active-class`. Example:

`<v-btn to="/test/111/mybox/222/333/444/detail/1" exact exact-active-class="custom-active-class"> Detail </v-btn>`

P/S: You'd better like use `name` instead of use full URL. `<v-btn to="{ name: ''yourURLName }" exact exact-active-class="custom-active-class"> Detail </v-btn>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `router-link` instade of `<v-btn>`
like this:

```
<router-link
:to="{
name: 'BoxManage',
params: {
        area: 'area of box',
        address: 'place of box' ,
        id: 77 ,
        box: 'value_of_box' ,
    }
}" 
class="some_class">Manage</router-link>
```

You can add any parameters as you want like this example ^_^

Comment: It's not work but thank you, after I add "exact" it's ok, thanks again.